# What it it called when you turn a lid to close a jar?

Tags: word-request

There's a jar, there's a thread on the top of the jar. What verb do you use when you take a lid, place it to the top of a jar, and then turn it clockwise until it tightly fits the jar? What do you do with the lid?

Comment: Are you talking about the *entire* process, or are you talking about what you do with the lid once it's already sitting on the jar? (There is a difference.) The title of your question seems to mean the latter, but the body of your question is describing the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **screw** the lid on. That type of lid is called a screw-on lid.

Comment: And you **unscrew** it to get it off.